# How to Decode a CSR in .net,php,cgi,etc

Tags: csr, decoder

How to Decode a CSR in .net,php,cgi,etc

wth a output like

CN
OU
O
L
S
C

Comment: As you don't appear to have started coding yet, read-up on this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request

Comment: i have started coding but i do not know were to start

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Easy in PHP:

```
$csr=$_POST['txtcsr'];  // Copy CSR to a variable
$data=openssl_csr_get_subject($csr);  // Get the subject of the CSR
print_r($data); // Print the output as an array:
```

Output: Array ( [C] => US [ST] => Minnesota [L] => Shakopee [O] => Test Organization [OU] => IT Arhitecture [CN] => your.domain [emailAddress] => your@email.com)

Tip: To get the function work, the server must have the OPENSSL_CNF environment variable correctly set.

Comment: Any suggestion for how to get following additional information ? 
- Signature algorithm
- Key algorithm
- Key size
and SAN (Subject Alternative Names) if it exist 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at OpenSSL modules for php and python for example.
[Php OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php)
[Python OpenSSL](http://packages.python.org/pyOpenSSL/)
You can check php **openssl_x509_parse()** function or use something like proc_open, os.popen to call openssl tool to do all the job and get results.